# how to trigger event with 'this' word with OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, prototype

I would like to trigger an events without duplicating code. So I decided to create a constructor function (class) and then a new object with a variable that connects to an event handler. Im just testing it but I cant get the `if` statement to trigger the `alert()` using `this.link` it works like this: if(el) but not like this: if(el === this.link)

```
var faqOne = document.getElementById("faqOne");
var hiddenOne = document.querySelector("p.faqOneHidden");    

faqOne.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    showFaqOne.showClickedFaq(e);
}, false);

function DisplayQFaqs(link, faq) {
    this.link = link;
    this.faq = faq;
}

DisplayQFaqs.prototype.showClickedFaq = function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    if (el === this.link) {
        alert('hi');
    }
};

var showFaqOne = new DisplayQFaqs(faqOne, hiddenOne);
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Works for me, no changes to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/93bm0gs3/

Comment: [And me](http://jsfiddle.net/n00rbqL1/2/)

Comment: I still cant get it to work locally, everything works, the alert() works with: if(el)  but not with if(el === this.link) ?

Comment: So then apparently `e.target` is not the element you expect. You've provided no HTML, which means you've no provided a reproduction of the issue. If I were to guess,  your `faqOne` element has descendants that are being clicked, which means you're comparing two different elements.

Comment: ...take @rgthree's jsFiddle demo and change the HTML to add a span inside, like this `<div id="faqOne">
    <span>Push me</span>
</div>` Is this something like what you have? This will cause the behavior you're experiencing. If so, then change `e.target` to `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: sorry it work, i had it wrapped in an anchor and swapped it for a div, thanks guys for the jsfiddle , thats where i saw you used a div

Comment: Yep! currentTarget is perfect! thanks squint!!